# How to restore access to wallet in Monerujo with restore password

Tags: wallet-recovery, monerujo

I forgot my passphrase but have written down Wallet Files Restore Password (CrAzYpass):

```
XXXX YYYY ZZZZ ...
```

How to use it? I don't see any restore button.

Answer (score 1):

Use it instead of normal password (passphrase).

**That's it.**